# Class method being called in main, changes don't persist outside class method?

Tags: c++, class, vector, methods, setter

Basically, I have two classes, Peg and Disk. (It's a Towers of Hanoi program) The files I have are Disk.h, Disk.cpp, Peg.h, Peg.cpp, and main.cpp. Not sure if that matters. Here's the disk class from Disk.h

```
#include <vector>
#include "gwindow.h"
#ifndef DISK_H
#define DISK_H

class Disk
{
private:
    int xCoord; //x and y coords are for drawing in a gwindow
    int yCoord;
    int mHeight;
    int mWidth;
    COLOR mColor;
    int mName;  //helps me keep track of which is which

public:
    Disk(); //default constructor
    Disk(int x, int y, int heightIn, int widthIn, COLOR colorIn);
    void setXY(int x, int y); //this is the one I'm having trouble with
    int getHeight();
    int getWidth();
    int getX();
    int getY();
    COLOR getColor();
    std::string diskColor();
    void draw(GWindow &gw);
    void nameDisk(int name);  //yet this one is working?
    int getName();
};

#endif
```

However, I'm having trouble with the setXY function. When I call it from main, it calls the function properly, changes the variable inside the scope of setXY, but the value doesn't persist outside the function. However, nameDisk works fine and is basically the same thing, except it is changing mName instead of xCoord and yCoord. Here is setXY:

```
void Disk::setXY(int x, int y)
{
    xCoord = x;
    yCoord= y;
}
```

and here is how I call it from main:

```
pegVec[2].getDisks()[0].setXY(690, 200);
```

I know this looks crazy, but basically pegVec is a vector of 3 peg objects. Each peg object has a function, getDisks(), which returns a vector of all the disks on that peg currently. So the line above is trying to perform setXY on the first peg on peg 2. Sorry if that's unclear, but I've tried making a new disk object and calling it on that and that didn't work either.

Here is getDisks, if it matters:

```
std::vector<Disk> Peg::getDisks()
{
    return disksOn;
}
```

and disksOn is just a member variable of Peg:

```
std::vector<Disk> disksOn;
```

I think it might be a problem with how getDisks() works. I'm a noob, but I'm guessing that returning the vector disksOn makes a "copy" of it, kind of, which is what I am altering with my setXY function but which is not the same as the actual disksOn vector associated with the Peg object? I don't know if that makes sense.

What I've tried so far:

- Making xCoord and yCoord public variables and updating them manually instead of making a setter function. This did not work.
- I printed out the x and y values at every step. Inside setXY, the values were updated successfully, but when the function ended they went back to how they were.
- I tried some mess with the const keyword, but I don't understand it and couldn't even get it to run.
- Passing everything by reference/value
- Making a new function in main which accepted a Disk vector as input, and using getDisks as input to that function. Didn't work, same problems.
- Tested my other setter function, nameDisk, which works fine. It's essentially the same as setXY, which is why I think the problem is with getDisks.
- Using pointers at various points (heh) throughout, but I wasn't sure the best way to do that. I was messing with it last night so I don't remember 100% but I think I tried to have getDisks return a pointer instead of the vector, and I don't think that worked, but it's more likely a problem with my syntax and how I used the pointer. I think that might work but I don't know how to shake it.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track - somehow you're looking at a different objects than what you think you are. Using references is a good solution, but you may not have got the right one ;-)

Try:

```
// Return reference to the disks on the peg.
std::vector<Disk>& Peg::getDisks()
{
    return disksOn;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that worked! Thank you so much. I remember trying that last night but I made it way more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that 
`std::vector<Disk> getDisks() { return disksOn; }`
returns a completely new and separate **temporary copy** of disksOn rather than a reference to the original. So you're modifying a temporary copy which gets discarded at the end of the statement.

You need to use
`std::vector<Disk> &getDisks() { return disksOn; }` in order to return a **reference** to disksOn.

Although if you are going to return a reference to the vector member object you might as well make the object directly accessible as public because anyone can manipulate the vector at this point and get rid of the getDisks() function as it serves no purpose in terms of access protection.

Better design would be to give access to individual disks:

```
Disk &getDisk(int index) { 
  return disksOn[index]; 
}

const Disk &getDisk(int index) const { 
  return disksOn[index]; 
}
```

The idea behind not giving direct access to the vector is that you can later change the underlying container type if needed without changing the code outside of the Peg class.

The second version (const) is necessary for accessing const Disks of const Peg objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain what the difference is between a const Disk object and a regular Disk object would be? Is the const Disk object immutable?

Comment: Put simply: yes. 

A **const** object is one you cannot change directly and can only call const member functions on it. It can however be changed by using a different non-const pointer or non-const reference to the same object, and some functions may cause it to change by doing a `const_cast<>()` which is necessary, for example, for implementing **reference-counted objects** as the reference-count needs to be updated even if the object is said to be const conceptually. So to be pedantic it is not strictly immutable.

Comment: For example `int a = 5; const int &const_ref_a = a; cout << const_ref_a  << "\n"; a = 10; cout << const_ref_a << "\n"; ` even though const_ref_a is a const reference to a, the object `a` can be changed. But `const_ref_a = 20;` will generate a compiler error. You have to see a **const** reference or pointer as a way to say "I don't intend to change the value using this reference (or pointer), compiler please tell me if I accidentally do" rather than "this value will never change" because in very complex systems you might get surprises.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that was really helpful- I get now why that would be a useful structure in some instances.